# ipv6 ndptool for neighbor discovery

Tags: ipv6

I'm trying to collect all global IPv6 addresses in LAN. So I'm using `ndptool` to see how many addresses I could collect.

The command could report router broadcast:

```
# ndptool  -i eth1 monitor -t ra
NDP payload len 96, from addr: fe80::4e5e:cff:feea:365, iface: eth1  
  Type: RA  
  Hop limit: 64  
  Managed address configuration: no  
  Other configuration: yes
```

but I failed with NS or NA type:

```
# ndptool -t ns -i eth1 monitor
```

returns nothing.

I used `tshark` to capture icmpv6,  like:

```
tshark -R icmpv6 -i eth1
```

and it shows packets were received:

```
4533 43.369934717 2001:b030:214:100:4e5e:cff:feea:366 -> ff02::1:ff78:99f9 ICMPv6 86 Neighbor Solicitation for 2001:b030:214:100:48d0:319d:5b78:99f9 from 4c:5e:0c:ea:03:66  
4578 44.014239120 fe80::1c41:89b5:6460:8e6d -> ff02::16     ICMPv6 110 Multicast Listener Report Message v2  
4601 44.369626481 2001:b030:214:100:4e5e:cff:feea:366 -> ff02::1:ff78:99f9 ICMPv6 86 Neighbor Solicitation for 2001:b030:214:100:48d0:319d:5b78:99f9 from 4c:5e:0c:ea:03:66  
4705 45.369780078 2001:b030:214:100:4e5e:cff:feea:366 -> ff02::1:ff78:99f9 ICMPv6 86 Neighbor Solicitation for 2001:b030:214:100:48d0:319d:5b78:99f9 from 4c:5e:0c:ea:03:66  
4761 45.747995672 fe80::4e5e:cff:feea:366 -> ff02::1:ff93:9da3 ICMPv6 86 Neighbor Solicitation for 2001:b030:214:100:20c:29ff:fe93:9da3 from 4c:5e:0c:ea:03:66  
4769 46.021538598 fe80::1c41:89b5:6460:8e6d -> ff02::16     ICMPv6 110 Multicast Listener Repo
```

It looks like the packets are there, but `ndptool` does not output them.

I hope to get the global IP and mac informations in LAN. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

ndptool is just a [wrapper over Neighbor Discovery Protocol messages](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/ndptool/). So it allows only sending and receiving NDP messages. If I understand correctly the protocol messages (e.g. from [How to: IPv6 Neighbor Discovery](https://blog.apnic.net/2019/10/18/how-to-ipv6-neighbor-discovery/)), an NA will be sent in response to an NS.
Try monitoring for NAs in one window, and sending NSs in another, and you will see that a neighbor responds with an NA.

Example, assuming *eth0* and a neighbor with *2001:db8::2*:

- in **window A**, run `ndptool -t na -i eth0 monitor`
- in **window B**, run `ndptool -t ns -i eth0 -D 2001:db8::2 send`
- in **window A**, observe `NDP payload len 24, from addr: 2001:db8::2, iface: eth0 ...`

If you need to know a neighbor's MAC address, try [ndisc6](https://www.remlab.net/ndisc6/)

```
# ndisc6 2001:db8::2 eth0
Soliciting 2001:db8::2 (2001:db8::2) on eth0...
Target link-layer address: 02:42:AC:14:00:02
 from 2001:db8::2
```

or [ip neighbor](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-neighbour.8.html)

```
# ip neigh show
2001:db8::2 dev eth0 lladdr 02:42:ac:14:00:02 STALE
```